# qemu cannot format a network drive when formatting C: in win95

Tags: linux, bash, qemu

[image: Console]

I am having issues where when I try to format the c: drive, its says its a network drive.

Start code:

```
qemu-system-i386 \
    -netdev user,id=mynet0 \
    -device ne2k_isa,netdev=mynet0 \
    -drive file=win95.disk,format=raw,media=disk \
    -soundhw sb16 \
    -m 1024 \
    -cpu pentium \
    -vga cirrus \
    -localtime \
    -drive file=disk01.img,format=raw,if=floppy \
    -drive file=win95_OSR25.iso,media=cdrom \
    -boot a \
    -soundhw pcspk
```

My `if` options are `ide`, `scsi`, `floppy`, and `virtio`.

Comment: it looks like you're trying to format something that looks like a CDROM drive to MSDOS. this might simply be the way QEMU drives work, but I'm not sure.

Comment: what `if=` options are available to you?

Comment: ide, scsi, floppy, and virtio, i belive

Comment: When asked for clarifications, please don't post the answer in the comment section, but edit the question to include that information. Reading through the command section is cumbersome, and comments are subject to removal without notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a different version of `qemu-system-i386` here. If I run `qeum-system-i386 --version` I get version 5.2.0, where for example the `-localtime` parameter has been switched to `-rtc base=localtime`.

I've downloaded DOS 6.22 from [AllBootDisks](https://www.allbootdisks.com/download/dos.html). When I run this command I get a DOS window available through VNC (as expected):

```
dd bs=1M count=100 if=/dev/zero of=disk.img
qemu-system-i386 -m 1024 -cpu pentium -vga cirrus -rtc base=localtime \
    -drive file=disk.img,format=raw,media=disk \
    -drive file=Dos6.22.img,format=raw,if=floppy \
    -boot a
```

If I try to `FORMAT C:` at this point I get told `Invalid drive specification`. This is expected because there is no MBR on the disk.

Use `FDISK` and follow the default prompts (`1`, `1`, `Y`, restart). Then you should be able to `FORMAT C:`.

Comment: Thanks, it wasnt -localtime, it was me using the windows95 boot image instead of the ms-dos floppy boot image, so I was able to fdisk and format the drive